# working with multiple remote desktop sessions

Tags: remote-desktop

I remote desktop from my home pc to my work pc. When on my work pc I often have to remote desktop from it to a web server. This expands in the whole the screen which means if I have to return the my work pc I must close down the remote desktop session in web server. The only way for security reasons I can access the web server is through work pc. Is there any way to minimize a remote desktop session (web server) and not having to close it?

Comment: Do you have the latest remote desktop client installed on your work PC?  You should be seeing a bar at the top o the screen that will allow you to minimize the second connection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We often use [Remote Desktop Connection Manager](http://www.petri.co.il/remote-desktop-connection-manager.htm) for managing our multiple RDP sessions.  It supports many of the features of Terminals and is free.

I hope that this helps.

Comment: +1 I **LOVE** RDCMan - the ability to arbitrarily group servers is brilliant, especially if you have servers at multiple sites.

Answer (score 1):

Using windows RDP client, the pinned toolbars at the top of the screen are covering each other so you can't see the toolbar on the web server. Two options I can think of:

1. Unpin the tool bar that appears in your work PC RDP session. This will make the tool bar auto-hide, exposing the toolbar of the web server
2. Before opening the RDP session to the web server, go to Options >> Display section of the RDP client and force the web server RDP session to open in a smaller window.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention your operating system.  If you are on Windows and have the ability to install software on your work system, you might find the Terminals application useful (http://terminals.codeplex.com/).  Among other features, it has a tabbed interface for remote sessions.  We use it quite a bit for exactly the situations you describe.

Answer (score 0):

No not really, VPN to work computer then directly RDP to server? I am not sure but it sounds like the title bar is going away, click the thumb tac and it will stay up.

Answer (score 0):

I use Royal TS:

http://www.code4ward.net/main/RoyalTS/Overview.aspx